# 特定のフレーズを検索するときの引用符「」が機能しない場合がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ, 検索

### 経緯

ヘルプセンターの「検索の方法は？」という記事に、特定のフレーズを検索する場合、または特殊文字の文字列を検索する場合の記法が以下のように記述されています<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)</sup>。

> ### 検索の方法は？ <sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)</sup>
>
> - 特定のフレーズを検索する場合、または特殊文字の文字列を検索する場合は、`「パンク」`、または `"<%#"` のように、引用符の中に入力します。

`「パンク」` と検索すると [`パンク` に一致するフレーズを持つ投稿のみが表示された](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%80%8C%E3%83%91%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%80%8D)ことから、私は `「perl」` とすると、 `perl` というフレーズが含まれた投稿のみが検索結果に表示されると思いました。

---

### 不具合事象

しかし、 `「javascript」` とすると、[自動的に `[javascript]` へ演算子が変化](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%80%8Cjavascript%E3%80%8D)してしまいます。これはタグ名として使用されている**一部の**文字列でのみ再現し、 `perl` では再現しませんでした ([`「perl」`](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%80%8Cperl%E3%80%8D))。また、フレーズ一致 (`「perl」`) とタグ一致 (`[perl]`) では検索結果の数が異なることは、 `"perl"` を用いることでわかります。

- [`[perl]`](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) での検索結果:  48 質問
- [`"perl"`](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22perl%22) での検索結果:  152 質問

以上より、現状の検索機能には以下の不具合があるのではないかと思います。

- タグ名として使用されている一部の文字列を引用符 `「」` では検索出来ない。
- 引用符 `「」` では検索出来ない文字列は、引用符 `「」` がタグを検索するときの演算子 `[]` に置き換わる。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現状、`「」` にはなにか特殊な作用（検索するとタグ表記に変化する）が有りそうですが、フレーズ検索の機能は有りません。ヘルプの記述を原文に合わせ、`" "` としました。

[ヘルプセンターの「検索の方法は？」を改善したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3957/3054)

Answer (score 6):

- [英語版の現在のヘルプページ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) を見ると、説明の二つ目は単に引用符で囲む内容のみです。

  > - To find a specific phrase, enter it in quotes: "flat tire".
- そもそも`「」`は **括弧** であり、引用符とする(日本語版での)説明が間違いだと思います。

経緯は把握できませんが、日本語版のヘルプページの訳が間違っているので見直すのが妥当かなと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。鍵括弧を引用符として使用する場合もあるため、その点で一概には言えないと思いますが、 [Wayback Machine で原文を読む限り](https://web.archive.org/web/20180424183449/https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)、翻訳ソフトか何かで翻訳した際、ダブルクォーテーションがそのまま鍵括弧になってしまったのではないか、と推測しています。