# ヘルプセンターの「検索の方法は？」を改善したい

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ, 検索

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching にいくつか修正すべき箇所があります。

#### 1点目

「ブール演算子」の `hascode:` の説明に余計な文字が含まれています。(全角小文字のL?)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 2点目

「削除された投稿」の `deleted:1` の説明が "削除された投稿のみを検索します" と訳されており、他人の投稿も含めたすべての削除済み投稿を検索できるかのように読めてしまいますが、原文では "searches only **your** deleted posts" なので、正確には "自分自身が作成した、削除された投稿のみを検索" となるはずです。(残り2つの説明は正しいものになっています)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

2点追加させて下さい。

#### 3点目

現在:

> 特定のフレーズを検索する場合、または特殊文字の文字列を検索する場合は、`「パンク」`、または `"<%#"` のように、引用符の中に入力します。

修正:

> 特定のフレーズを検索する場合は `"hello world"`のように引用符の中に入力します。

関連:

[特定のフレーズを検索するときの引用符「」が機能しない場合がある](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3113/3054)
[特殊文字を検索する場合の演算子が正常に機能していない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3114/3054)

#### 4点目

現在:

> 自分が自身

修正:

> 自分自身